# JQuery UI function errors out: Object is not a property or method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

In the following code I get an error that says autocomplete function Object is not a property or method

Here is the code:

```
<title><%= ViewData["pagetitle"] + " | " + config.Sitename.ToString() %></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            Categories();

            $('#tags1').autocomplete({ //error here
                url: '/Tag/TagAutoComplete',
                width: 320,
                max: 4,
                delay: 30,
                cacheLength: 1,
                scroll: false,
                highlight: false
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because the script are not found in the indicated location. I would recommend you using helpers for this. For example instead of writing:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

always write:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js") %>"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) that all the required scripts are properly loaded and that you don't have any javascript errors.

Comment: OMG..Thank you for telling me to check firebug..Actually I the jquery file and my javascript file was called in my master page and the local page, which made jquery error out. I found out by checking what was loaded in firebug. If I would have never checked that - I would have been stuck for days. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

why are you having two of this `jquery.ui.core.min.js` ?

and I see that you did not include jQuery libray... did you?

Comment: OK..i took the extra one off and it still says the same thing

Comment: you did not include jQuery.js, did you? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js

Comment: yes i sure did but it was added twicw. once in my local page and once in my master page. i guess made autocomplete fail